# Colums name of saved search with suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am using suite script (API version is 1.0). I have created a Saved search for transaction in netsuite account.
Now I want to pull the data from saved search into my database, but before this just want to list the columns present in saved search on my mapping screen.

For this I have written below script:

```
function GetColumnName()
{
        var s = nlapiLoadSearch('transaction', 'customsearchtestsavedsearchwithcustfield');
        var columns = s.getColumns();
        return columns;
}
```

but in above code getColumns function is not working and netsuite giving below error (error does not say much)

```
TITLE
**UNEXPECTED_ERROR**
TYPE
System
DATE & TIME
8/17/2017 4:34 am
DETAILS
```

Can any one please help me regarding this.

Thanks

Comment: What are the Columns you've set up in this Saved Search?

Comment: Account, department, amount and some other including custom segments, custom body fields

Comment: today I am able to debug my script in Netsuite debugger and found some more details on error, now error says: UNEXPECTED_ERROR 8/17/2017 21:54:25.887
  ReferenceError: "nlapiLoadSearch" is not defined. (adhoc$-1$debugger.user#26). sorry for my above comment. error comes only with SuiteScript 2.0, in SuiteScript 1.0 it works.

Comment: one more thing, my script type is Restlet

Comment: I have a whole series of videos on transitioning from SuiteScript 1.0 to 2.0 here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLG2tK6Va2WUDhhcdhklK7wsqmVN-oNF-P

Comment: Thanks for sharing so useful link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will give you the result you are looking for. Just pass in the nlobjSearch object and it will return an array of the Column names. This is verified as functional, if you still receive an error then there is something wrong with the search being loaded and you should diagnose this search in the UI.

```
function searchColTitles(search) { // search is the nlobjSearch from an nlapiLoadSearch(), or nlapiCreateSearch()

var columns = [];
var c;
var cName;
var columnNames = [];


columns = search.getColumns();

for (c = 0; columns.length && c < columns.length; c += 1) {
    cName = columns[c].label;
    if (!cName) {
        cName = columns[c].name;
    }
    columnNames.push(cName);
}

return columnNames;
```

}

Comment: Thanks, above script is working fine in SuiteScript 1.0, but in 2.0 it error says "nlapiLoadSearch  is not defined"

Comment: @user2626026 Correct, anything that starts with nlapi is a 1.0 api. For 2.0 you would need to load the search module, then use the search.loadSearch({options}). Check the help documentation for more information on 2.0 if needed.

Comment: Thanks. My script on netsuite has API level 1.0. so when debugging on netsuite with 1.0 it works, but when accessing my deployed script from my sample c# application, giving me above error. Is there is a way to know which api netsuite is using when I am calling Restlet from c#

Comment: I am marking your anwser is correct as it work fine in SuiteScript 1.0

Comment: @user2626026 The API version will depend entirely on which version the RESTlet was created in. You would have to know beforehand that the RESTlet you are calling was written in 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Yes, I have created my RESTlet using 1.0